# Epsilon-Delta Continuity proof (verification/help)

Tags: proof-verification, continuity

So, I am really bad at these problems, and I don't know why.

Edit: The metric over $\Bbb R$ is assumed to be $|f(a,b)-f(x_1,x_2)|$

Problem statement:

Define $f: \Bbb R^2 \rightarrow \Bbb R$ by $f(x_1,x_2) = x_1 + x_2$.

Prove that $f$ is continuous under:

a. $d((x_1,x_2),(a,b)) = \max\{|x_1-a|,|x_2-b|\}$

and b. $d'((x_1,x_2),(a,b)) = \sqrt{(x_1-a)^2+(x_2-b)^2}$

Attempt under metric (a) (I think I did this one correctly.)

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Choose $\delta = \epsilon/2$.

Then, $$\max\{|x_1-a|,|x_2-b|\}<\delta \implies |x_1-a|+|x_2-b| < 2\delta \implies |x_1-a|+|x_2-b| < \epsilon$$

By triangle inequality, $$|x_1-a+x_2-b| \leq |x_1-a|+|x_2-b| \implies |f(x_1,x_2) - f(a,b)| \leq |x_1-a|+|x_2-b| < \epsilon $$

Therefore, $|f(x_1,x_2) - f(a,b)| < \epsilon$, so this is continuous.

Attempt at (b).

Again, let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Then ... I am not really sure which $\delta$ to choose. Does anyone have any hints?

Comment: $a,b$ are parameters? Or $(a,b)$ is another pair of points?

Comment: $(a,b)$ is to be considered another ordered pair, yes.

Comment: Lastly, what is your metric on $\mathbb{R}$? You've only given metrics on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: The metric on $\Bbb R$ actually wasn't given but I am extremely sure it is just $|f(a,b) - f(x_1,x_2)|$, since that is what the book has been using for examples.

Comment: Do you understand geometrically what the second metric means?

Comment: It is a circle of radius $\delta$ centered about the ordered pair $(a,b)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another hint, for the second part:

What is the furthest (under the standard metric) we can get from the center of a disk at the origin of radius $\delta$ under your $f$?

That is, what is $\max \{|x_1+x_2|\}$ subject to $x_1^2+x_2^2\leq1$?

What about $\max \{|x_1+x_2|\}$ subject to $x_1^2+x_2^2\leq\delta^2$?

What about $\max \{|x_1+x_2|\}$ subject to $\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}\leq\delta$?

Comment: Oh, wow. I guess if would still just be either $x$ or $y$.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure you followed. I've broken it down into two steps.

Comment: Ok, the max of $x+y$ under the contraints $x^2+y^2=\delta^2$. With Lagrange multipliers I got $x+y\leq\sqrt2\delta$, so I should choose $\epsilon/\sqrt2 = \delta$?

Comment: Sounds like you've got it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is where you write $|x_1-a+x_2-b|$.  That is not the distance from $(x_1,x_2)$ to $(a,b)$.  It is $\max\{|x_1-a|,|x_2-b|\}$.  You have to relate the two things otherwise there's a gap in your argument.

Comment: Yes. I assumed that if the max is less than $\delta$, then the sum of both of those distances has to be less than $2\delta$. Is this a valid argument?

Comment: You are using $\max\{|x_1-a|,|x_2-b|\}<\delta$ $\Rightarrow$ $|x_1-a|+|x_2-b|<2\delta$.  Just make that explicit.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I probably should have made that a little more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Write down *explicitly* and *carefully* the definition of continuity for your "non-standard" metrics.

Comment: So, if $d'((a,b),(x_1,x_2)) < \delta \implies d(f(a,b),f(x_1,x_2)) < \epsilon$. I need to solve for $\delta(\epsilon)$ but I am not sure which $\delta$ to choose.

Comment: You have the right $\delta$, but as @GregoryGrant's pointed out, your logical progression from proof beginning to end is still a bit sloppy.

Comment: Alright. I have edited it to make my logic a little more clear. How can I solve this under the second metric, though?

Answer (score 1):

Take $\delta=\frac{1}{2}\epsilon$!